# Casting Transformation to Column in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table that looks as follows:

| City | Value |
| --- | --- |
| <String> | <String> |
| Chicago | 12 |
| Detriot | 15 |
| Jersery City | 20 |

This table is locked in this format:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([('Chicago', '12'),('Detriot', '15'),('Jersery City', '20')])
```

I did some research on Stack Overflow and came to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521402/python-numpy-change-the-column-type-of-a-numpy-matrix). However I don't know why it is not working. I tried the following code:

```
x[:,1] = x[:,1].astype(int)
```

I even tried the following as well and it did not work:

```
x[:,[1]] = x[:,[1]].astype(int)
```

However this line when run returns the following:

```
type(x[0,1])
numpy.str_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy array only support **uniform types**. Thus, all the items of an array should be of the same type (you can retrieve it using `x.dtype`), like `np.float64` or `np.int64` for example.

The type of the **items in `x` cannot change at runtime**. `x[:,1] = x[:,1].astype(int)` performs an implicit conversion so that the types matches. If you need that, then you have to **create a new array**.

Note that this type can be `object`. In such a situation, any Python object can be stored in the Numpy array. However, this is generally a bad idea to use `object` types since they are inefficiently stored in memory, defeat any possible low-level vectorization (ie. slow) and cause performance issues in parallel (because of the GIL).

Note also that Numpy provides structured types to store (quite) complex data structure in each array item.

Comment: So string supersedes int?

Comment: It is not due to type "superseding". It is due to implicit conversions Numpy does in your case. It does the conversion because of the static array type rule (without an implicit conversion, the assignment would not be valid because the types mismatch between the left and the right part of the assignment statement).