# Numpy ndarray object with string and floating point number types in it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file text with data in a following format:

rubbish & 3.97& 3.83& 3.95& 3.83& 3.82

rubbish & 4.92& 4.81& 4.88& 4.81& 4.81

rubbish & 5.90& 5.66& 5.88& 5.66& 5.66

rubbish &---  & 6.05& 6.14& 6.05& 6.05

rubbish & 6.42& 6.26& 6.46& 6.26& 6.26

rubbish &---  & 6.56& 6.63& 6.56& 6.56

And I want to read them into numpy.ndarray object so that numbers are transformed into floating point number object while the `---` stay as the string objects. However, the following piece of code creates an expected numpy.array object but everything in there is a string.

```
import numpy as np

wejscie = open('data.dat', 'r').readlines()

def fun1(x):

  print x
  if x.strip() == '---':

    return str(x)

  else:

    return float(x)

dane = np.array([map(fun1, linijka.split('&')[1:]) for linijka in wejscie])
```

So is it possible to have numpy.ndarray object containing data of various types?

Comment: Try `return np.nan` instead of `return str(x)`.  Or some other float value that will be place holder for the string.  You can't mix strings and floats in an array like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `fun1`, it's with trying to insert elements of differing types into a numpy array.

Consider the following:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1])
>>> numpy.append(a,2)
array([1, 2])
>>> numpy.append(a,'b')
array(['1', 'b'],
  dtype='<U11')
```

You may find this helpful [Store different datatypes in one NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array)