# concatenate arrays with mixed types

Tags: python, numpy

consider the `np.array` `a`

```
a = np.concatenate(
    [np.arange(2).reshape(-1, 1),
     np.array([['a'], ['b']])],
    axis=1)
a

array([['0', 'a'],
       ['1', 'b']], 
      dtype='|S11')
```

How can I execute this concatenation such that the first column of `a` remains integers?

Comment: You can't. numpy arrays are *homogeneous*. Each array has **an** element type.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes but that type can be a `numpy.object`

Comment: The 'duplicate' describes a different approach - using recarray or structured arrays.  The result will be a 1d array with 2 fields, not a 2d array.  Which is better depends on what else you need to do with the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix types in a numpy array by using a `numpy.object` as the `dtype`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.empty((2, 0), dtype=np.object)
>>> a = np.append(a, np.arange(2).reshape(-1,1), axis=1)
>>> a = np.append(a, np.array([['a'],['b']]), axis=1)
```

```
>>> a
array([[0, 'a'],
       [1, 'b']], dtype=object)
```

```
>>> type(a[0,0])
<type 'int'>
```

```
>>> type(a[0,1])
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: just to clarify. note that while the individual elements are integers. the column itself would be a numpy object; i.e. if you explicitly wanted a slice to be an array of integers you need to convert the type explicitly at the point of calling, e.g. `np.array(a[:,0], dtype=np.int64)`

Answer (score 3):

A suggested duplicate recommends making a recarray or structured array.

[Store different datatypes in one NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array)

In this case:

```
In [324]: a = np.rec.fromarrays((np.arange(2).reshape(-1,1), np.array([['a'],['b']])))
In [325]: a
Out[325]: 
rec.array([[(0, 'a')],
 [(1, 'b')]], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<U1')])
In [326]: a['f0']
Out[326]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
In [327]: a['f1']
Out[327]: 
array([['a'],
       ['b']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

(I have reopened this because I think both approaches need to acknowledged.  Plus the `object` answer was already given and accepted.)

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj; I confess I neglected to check for duplicates first when I gave my answer; glad it's adding something of benefit though.

Comment: It's often easier (and faster) to write an answer than to look for duplicates.  But sometimes the sidebar does a good job of finding them.