# Python 3 Numpy File CSV convert to narray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got a `ndarray` which I am trying to read from a CSV file.
I can read it via `numpy` from a file but can't get the structure I want; instead of a 2D array I have an array of tuples

As a MCVE: instead of a 2D array like `DataSet1`, I have `DataSet2`:

```
dataset=numpy.array([
        ["abc ",3000.0,1],
        ["def",3650.0,1],
        ["xyz",3000.0,2]        
        ])
print("DataSet1\n",dataset)
print("DataSet1-Shape\n",dataset.shape)


dataset2=numpy.array([])

dataset2 = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=",",dtype='S32,float,int')

print("DataSet2\n",dataset2)
print("DataSet2-Shape\n",dataset2.shape)
```

The output is:

```
DataSet1
 [['abc ' '3000.0' '1']
 ['def' '3650.0' '1']
 ['xyz' '3000.0' '2']]
DataSet1-Shape
 (3, 3)
DataSet2
 [(b'"fabc"', 3000.0, 1) (b'"fdef"', 3650.0, 1) (b'"ghi"', 3000.0, 2)]
DataSet2-Shape
 (3,)
```

I want DataSet2 to be the 2D as DataSet1.

CSV file contents:

```
"fabc",3000.0,1
"fdef",3650.0,1
"ghi",3000.0,2
```

Comment: Could you include the content of your csv ?

Comment: For now csv is 3 lines, but will grow:
   "fabc",3000.0,1
   "fdef",3650.0,1
   "ghi",3000.0,2

Comment: Please edit your question to include this (I guess there are \n characters missing too)

Comment: So you are happy that `Dataset1` is just strings?  You can load the CSV directly like that.  Try dtype `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension and casting tuples to lists with `np.array([list(tup) for tup in dataset2])` should work:

```
>>> np.array([list(tup) for tup in dataset2])
array([['"fabc"', '3000.0', '1'],
       ['"fdef"', '3650.0', '1'],
       ['"ghi"', '3000.0', '2']], 
      dtype='|S6')
>>> np.array([list(tup) for tup in dataset2]).shape
(3, 3)
```

Also notice your `dataset2 = numpy.array([])` is useless because `dataset2` is overwritten next line. 
Edit: `[list(tup) for tup in dataset2]` is the result of `map(list, dataset2)`

For mixed types in np arrays see [Store different datatypes in one NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array); I suggest you use a `pandas.DataFrame` instead.

Comment: Almost works... except each field value is now a string:
    [[b'"fabc"' b'3000.0' b'1']
    [b'"fdef"' b'3650.0' b'1']
    [b'"ghi"' b'3000.0' b'2']]

Comment: numpy arrays can have only one type, I think. You can use a pandas.DataFrame if you want mixed type (just do df=pd.DataFrame(your_array))

Comment: `dataset2.tolist()` works just as well as your list comprehension.  `np.array` treats the tuples just like lists - unless given a compound dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Your compound `dtype` loaded the file as a 1d array with 3 fields

```
In [195]: data=np.genfromtxt('stack39872346.txt',delimiter=',',dtype='S32,float,int')
In [196]: data
Out[196]: 
array([(b'"fabc"', 3000.0, 1), (b'"fdef"', 3650.0, 1),
       (b'"ghi"', 3000.0, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S32'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])
In [197]: data.shape
Out[197]: (3,)
In [198]: data.dtype
Out[198]: dtype([('f0', 'S32'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Your `Dataset1` is 2d with string dtype:

```
In [207]: Dataset1
Out[207]: 
array([['abc ', '3000.0', '1'],
       ['def', '3650.0', '1'],
       ['xyz', '3000.0', '2']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

Converting a compound dtype to a simple one is a little tricky.  It can be done with `astype`.  But perhaps it is simpler to use the list version of `data` as the intermediary.

```
In [203]: data.tolist()
Out[203]: [(b'"fabc"', 3000.0, 1), (b'"fdef"', 3650.0, 1), (b'"ghi"', 3000.0, 2)]
In [204]: np.array(data.tolist())
Out[204]: 
array([[b'"fabc"', b'3000.0', b'1'],
       [b'"fdef"', b'3650.0', b'1'],
       [b'"ghi"', b'3000.0', b'2']], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

`np.array` has read the list of tuples, and created a 2d array with the most-common type, `S6` (Py3 bytestring)

Now it is easy to convert to unicode string with `astype`:

```
In [205]: np.array(data.tolist()).astype("U6")
Out[205]: 
array([['"fabc"', '3000.0', '1'],
       ['"fdef"', '3650.0', '1'],
       ['"ghi"', '3000.0', '2']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

This is similar to `Dataset1`, except that the first column is double quoted.

I could skip the last `astype` by specifying `dtype`: `np.array(data.tolist(),dtype=str)`

Better yet, tell that to the `genfromtxt`:

```
np.genfromtxt('stack39872346.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=str)
```

A nice thing about the original compound dtype is that you can access the numeric fields as numbers:

```
In [214]: data['f1']
Out[214]: array([ 3000.,  3650.,  3000.])
In [215]: Dataset1[:,1]
Out[215]: 
array(['3000.0', '3650.0', '3000.0'], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

I haven't addressed the double quotes.  The `csv` reader can strip those; `genfromtxt` does not.  Though fortunately you don't have delimiters within the quotes, so I could write a `converter` that would strip them off during the `genfromtxt` read.

=================

```
def foo(astr):
    return astr[1:-1] # crude dequote

In [223]: data=np.genfromtxt('stack39872346.txt',delimiter=',',
     dtype='U6,float,int', converters={0:foo})
In [224]: data
Out[224]: 
array([('fabc', 3000.0, 1), 
       ('fdef', 3650.0, 1), 
       ('ghi', 3000.0, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U6'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [225]: np.array(data.tolist())
Out[225]: 
array([['fabc', '3000.0', '1'],
       ['fdef', '3650.0', '1'],
       ['ghi', '3000.0', '2']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

It looks like I have to use a compound dtype when loading with a `converter`.