# How to create a numpy array to describe the vertices of a triangle?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, glsl

I like to use Numpy to create an array of vertices that is to be passed into `glsl`.

`Vertices` will be a numpy array that comprises the info of 3 vertex.

Each `vertex` consist of:

1. `pos = (x, y)` a 64-bit signed floating-point format that has a 32-bit
   R component in bytes 0..3, and a 32-bit G component in bytes 4..7,
   and
2. `color = (r, g, b)` a 96-bit signed floating-point format that has a
   32-bit R component in bytes 0..3, a 32-bit G component in bytes
   4..7, and a 32-bit B component in bytes 8..11

i.e. each `vertex = (pos, color) = ( (x, y), (r, g, b) )`

A triangle has 3 vertices, so finally I need a 1D numpy array to describe

```
Vertices = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex3]
         = [ ( (x, y), (r, g, b) ), 
             ( (x, y), (r, g, b) ), 
             ( (x, y), (r, g, b) ) ]
```

**How can I create `Vertices` in numpy?** The below syntax looks wrong.

```
Vertices = np.array([( (x1, y1), (r1, g1, b1) ), 
                     ( (x2, y2), (r2, g2, b2) ), 
                     ( (x3, y3), (r3, g3, b3) )], dtype=np.float32)
```

The bytes size of each `vertex` should be 64/8 + 96/8 = 8 + 12 = 20 bytes.
The bytes size of `Vertices` should be 20 bytes x 3 = 60 bytes.

Comment: I think you should be more precise about the actual problem you are facing. Until now, you are only describing the output data but not the input data or anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store different datatypes in one NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple, in `numpy` actually. Use [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
In [21]: PosType = np.dtype([('x','f4'), ('y','f4')])

In [22]: ColorType = np.dtype([('r','f4'), ('g', 'f4'), ('b', 'f4')])

In [23]: VertexType = np.dtype([('pos', PosType),('color', ColorType)])

In [24]: VertexType
Out[24]: dtype([('pos', [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')]), ('color', [('r', '<f4'), ('g', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])])

In [25]: VertexType.itemsize
Out[25]: 20
```

Then simply:

```
In [26]: vertices = np.array([( (1, 2), (3, 4, 5) ),
    ...:                      ( (6, 7), (8, 9, 10) ),
    ...:                      ( (11, 12), (13, 14, 15) )], dtype=VertexType)

In [27]: vertices.shape
Out[27]: (3,)
```

And basic indexing:

```
In [28]: vertices[0]
Out[28]: (( 1.,  2.), ( 3.,  4.,  5.))

In [29]: vertices[0]['pos']
Out[29]: ( 1.,  2.)

In [30]: vertices[0]['pos']['y']
Out[30]: 2.0

In [31]: VertexType.itemsize
Out[31]: 20
```

`numpy` ever provides record-arrays, so you can use attribute-access instead of indexing:

```
In [32]: vertices = np.rec.array([( (1, 2), (3, 4, 5) ),
    ...:                          ( (6, 7), (8, 9, 10) ),
    ...:                          ( (11, 12), (13, 14, 15) )], dtype=VertexType)

In [33]: vertices[0].pos
Out[33]: (1.0, 2.0)

In [34]: vertices[0].pos.x
Out[34]: 1.0

In [35]: vertices[2].color.g
Out[35]: 14.0
```

Comment: May I know what does `'f4'` and `'<f4'` in `np.dtype` mean? What is the diff btw `'f4'` and `np.float32`?

Comment: @SunBear it's the string-specification shorthand, see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) I linked to for more details.  `f4` is the 4-byte floating point type in native byte-order, it is the same thing as a `np.float32`.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the concept of Structured arrays. Exactly what I needed. :)