# improve performance of list creation

Tags: python, list, performance, numpy

**How can I improve significantly the speed of the following code?** Can mapping, numpy, matrix operations be efficiently used and/or something else to omit the for loop?

```
import time

def func(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return 'even'
    else:
        return 'odd'

starttime = time.time()

MAX=1000000

y=list(range(MAX))

for n in range(MAX):
    y[n]=[n,n**2,func(n)]

print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

The following replacement does not improve the speed:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.array(range(MAX))
str = ['odd', 'even']
result = np.array([r, r ** 2, list(map(lambda x: str[x % 2], r))])
y = result.T
```

Comment: NumPy solution produces all string output, which is different from your non NumPy version. So, are you okay with an all string output?

Comment: If this performance is really, really important to you, look into re-writing it in `c`: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Comment: @Divakar we can use `np.rec.fromarrays` :)

Comment: Do you have to create the whole list, or can you use a generator for your purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer would be **you can't**.

Let's explore this a bit through examples.

```
# Original code
y=list(range(MAX))
for n in range(MAX):
    y[n]=[n,n**2,func(n)]

# That took 0.86 seconds
```

This is the result on my machine so we have a baseline for comparison.
Let us make that a single line and shave off some time.

```
y = [[n, n ** 2, func(n)] for n in range(MAX)]

# That took 0.74 seconds
```

We are creating a list of lists and the Python interpreter needs to allocate an empty list `MAX` times.

In case you don't need to change the number of elements after initialization it might be better to use tuples instead of lists.

```
y = [(n, n ** 2, func(n)) for n in range(MAX)]

# That took 0.43 seconds
```

This is twice as fast as the original method.
Let's now assume that we can optimize even more by using some special library and then we just need to parse the result to populate the list. To simulate this we can `pickle` the list to a binary format and then measure the time it takes to load it.

```
import pickle

b = pickle.dumps([(n, n ** 2, func(n)) for n in range(MAX)])

starttime = time.time()
y = pickle.loads(b)
print('That took {:.2f} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))

# That took 0.23 seconds
```

This is probably close to what is possible to achieve without coding anything in a lower level language like C and creating Python objects from that language.

#### Alternative approach

If there is no requirement to create exactly the same object as in the original example and if it is enough that we can read `y[10]` or `y[100:1000]` we can do something completely different.

```
class LazyList():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            r = range(self.size)[key]
            return [(n, n ** 2, func(n)) for n in r]

        return (key, key ** 2, func(key))

starttime = time.time()
y = LazyList(MAX)

print('That took {:.6f} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))

# That took 0.000005 seconds
```

This is multiple orders of magnitude faster. Of course, this is not a list and the results of the computation are not in memory. We created an object that will in some cases act like a list, but not in other cases (e.g. `y[MAX*2]` will work, even though it shouldn't). Note that with more work, the object can become even more similar to a list and also use a list as its base class.

If the object we got is converted to a list, the process spends the time that was saved by the alternative approach and the result is the same as in one of the previous examples.

```
y = y[:]

# That took 0.43 seconds
```

The longer answer is that it depends on the type of the result that is expected.

Comment: This solution is very interesting. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it this way, the idea is to use as many `numpy` built-in functions as possible

```
%%timeit
y = np.arange(MAX)
y_2 = y**2
y_str = np.where(y%2==0,'even','odd')

res = np.rec.fromarrays((y,y_2,y_str), names=('y', 'y_2', 'y_str'))

#
# Some examples for working with the record array
res[3]
# (3, 9, 'odd')
res[:3]
# rec.array([(0, 0, 'even'), (1, 1, 'odd'), (2, 4, 'even')],
#           dtype=[('y', '<i8'), ('y_2', '<i8'), ('y_str', '<U4')])
res['y_str'][:7]
# array(['even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even'], dtype='<U4')
res.y_2[:7]
# array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36])
```

I have ran several tests, and it is significantly faster.

Comment: Good use case for record arrays! But should the call not rather look something like this `np.rec.fromarrays((y, y_2, y_str), names=('y', 'y2', 'y_str'))`? Or leave `names` empty, but naming 2 of the 3 arrays `data` and `keys` seems strange to me.

Comment: @scleronomic Thanks! Actually, I didn't know about record arrays before I answered this question, I learnt about it from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310158/8366805. As you pointed out, it is strange to name 2 of the three arrays, but naming all the three arrays like `res = np.rec.fromarrays((y,y_2,y_str),names=('data','data','keys'))` raised an error `ValueError: Duplicate field names: ['data']`, I'm really confused...

Comment: `data` and `keys` are not mandatory names for the arrays, it was just fitting for the post you linked.  In general you should choose names that fit to the arrays you pass. And of course they have to be unique, otherwise you could not access them like `res[name]`.
If you pass no names, the arrays get the names f0,  f1, f2... And in your case the array `y_str` gets the name `f2` as no third name is provided

Comment: @scleronomic Thank you for clarifying this! I didn't realize `rec.fromarrays` will automatically detect the types of the arrays, if I commented the `names`, `rec.fromarrays` will still work, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For large arrays of the same type, numpy is the way to go.  But numpy `where` is slow, so if you just want 'odd' and 'even', you can use `np.tile` or something like it:

```
MAX = 1000000

%%timeit
y = np.arange(MAX)
ystr = np.where(y%2==0,'even','odd')
#  14.9 ms ± 61.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
temp = np.array(['even', 'odd'])
ystr = np.tile(temp, MAX//2)
# 4.1 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So `tile` is about 3-4x faster.

If you want something more complex, I'd still try to avoid `where` if speed is important.  There's almost always a way because the `where` logic is usually simple so it's easy to take the logical expression that was inside the `where` and write it as an expression between numpy arrays.  (Also, to be sure, using numpy and `where` will be much faster than pure Python lists, it's just usually slow relative to other numpy options.)

The others are fairly obvious:

```
y = np.arange(MAX) 
y2 = y**2
```

Personally, I'd just stick these together in a list,

```
result = [y, y2, ystr]
```

Putting this all together (using `tile`), I get:

```
# 6.82 ms ± 84.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: How does `tile` stack up to indexing: `np.array(['even', 'odd'])[np.arange(whatever) % 2]`?

Answer (score 1):

See below (it takes ~ 1 sec on my mac)

```
import time

MAX = 1000000

starttime = time.time()

y = [[n, n ** 2, 'even' if n % 2 == 0 else 'odd'] for n in range(MAX)]

print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant one-liner. But the speed is about the same as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to run it with multiple processes in parallel:

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def func(x):
    return [x, x ** 2, "even" if x % 2 == 0 else "odd"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    starttime = time.time()
    MAX = 1000000
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    y = pool.map(func, range(MAX))
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Try to tune the number of processes to get the optimal value for your environment. On mine, it took ~0.8 secs with 20 processes while your original snippet took ~1.1 secs.

Comment: I get an error when ´pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)´ is called. >RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module: if name == 'main': freeze_support() ... ---- My computer has one CPU with 4 cores.

Comment: Great, now the code works, but the speed compared to my code is approximately the same. How can that be?

Comment: Try to tune the number of processes. Start from 5 for example and increase until you don't see performance improvement.

Comment: There's a lot of overhead involved in sending the data. More processes can actually slow you down. It's not a magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` approach:

```
import time
import numpy as np
starttime = time.time()

r = np.arange(MAX)
res = [r, r ** 2, np.where(r % 2, 'odd', 'even')]

print('That took {:.4} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
# That took 0.05125 seconds  || original function took 1.5s
```

As @Divakar pointed out, how to move on from here depends on what end result you want.
One option would be to have an object array with mixed types:

```py
res = np.array(res, dtype=object).T
print('That took {:.4} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
# That took 0.1863 seconds

res[17]
# array([17, 289, 'odd'], dtype=object)
res[18] + res[17] 
# array([35, 613, 'evenodd'], dtype=object)  # add for int and str
```

Unfortunately it is quite expansive to combine the 3 different arrays. It is still way faster than using loops but depending on your next steps you could maybe make further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer:

- the original loop took about 1.01 seconds
- NumPy solution took 10.3 ms
- Numba solution took 4.25 ms

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

def f(n_max = 1_000_000):
    y = x ** 2
    z = x % 2
    return y, z

@njit
def g(x):
    y = x ** 2
    z = x % 2
    return y, z

n_max = 1_000_000
x = np.arange(n_max, dtype=int)
```

NumPy:

```
%%timeit
y, z = f(x)
10.3 ms ± 296 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And Numba:

```
y, z = g(x) # don't time first run, which does compile AND execute

%%timeit
y, z = g(x)
4.25 ms ± 85.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```