# Best way to make horizontal tuples into numpy array columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parsing, tuples

```
tuple_columns = ('distance', 'speed', 'momentum', 'name', 'friend')
tuple_input = [
(3, 4, 6, 'er', 'ere'),
(3, 4, 6, 'er', 'ere'),
(3, 4, 6, 'er', 'ere'),
(3, 4, 6, 'er', 'ere'),
]
```

What's the best way to create numpy arrays that are vertical columns from this dataset which is initially a list of horizontal tuples?

Comment: I see you've tagged your question with [tag:pandas] . Do you want to create pandas dataframe from these values?

Answer (score 0):

NumPy array does not allow array with different types, so you cannot directly have an array with both int and str, there is a workaround:

```
new_arr = np.array(tuple_input, dtype=object)
```

it gives the following array

```
[[3 4 6 'er' 'ere']
[3 4 6 'er' 'ere']  
[3 4 6 'er' 'ere']  
[3 4 6 'er' 'ere']]
```

also, or if you want each tuple to be the column of your new array, you can do:

```
new_arr = np.array(tuple_input, dtype=object).T
```

which results in the following array.

```
[[3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [6 6 6 6]
 ['er' 'er' 'er' 'er']
 ['ere' 'ere' 'ere' 'ere']]
```

However, I do want to warn you that, I personally think having an array of type object is not good. It might have potential problems when you perform certain operations.
for example, according to a comment by Astrid from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058285/14436930

> Suppose, for argument's sake, that you turned that into a dataframe.
> And then you wanted to filter objects in that dataframe say
> df.loc[(df.col == item)] well that would not work because when pandas
> does the filtering it expects all the items to be of the same type. So
> if, for example, you were to mix strings and integers in the same
> column then you would be comparing apples and oranges effectively. And
> hence pandas would throw an error

And even if it does not cause problems in your case, forcing int and str to be only objects is not a very good programming habit

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataFrame directly like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tuple_input)
df.columns = tuple_columns
```

And if you want a numpy array matrix, then you can use:

```
df_array = df.values
```

Or

```
df_array = df.to_numpy()
```

But the above method won't be able to retain your header values, to retain the header you can use a [record array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) which is an ndarray subclass that allows field access using attributes. Likewise:

```
df_records = df.to_records(index = False)
```