# Python Numpy return elements in ndarray that are strings

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to get the elements in an ndarray that are strings. That is, exclude the elements that are integers and floats.

Lets say I have this array:

`x = np.array([1,'hello',2,'world'])`

I want it to return:

`array(['hello','world'],dtype = object)`

I've tried doing `np.where(x == np.str_)` to get the indices where that condition is true, but it's not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you check `x` after your first line, you'll notice the entire array has `dtype='<U11'` therefore there is nothing to filter

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array) that discusses heterogeneous data in numpy.

Comment: Run `type(x[0])` and you will see that the integers are actually being stored as `numpy.str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function to do it, and loop over the array:

```
def getridofnumbers(num):
    try:
        x = int(num)
    except:
        return True
    return False

output = np.array([i for i in x if getridofnumbers(i)])
```

if we want to keep all the numpy goodness (broadcasting etc), we can convert that into a [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) using vectorize (or np.frompyfunc):

```
import numpy as np
#vectorize the fucntion, with a boolean return type
getrid = np.vectorize(getridofnumbers, otypes=[bool])

x[getrid(x)]
array(['hello', 'world'], dtype='<U11')

#or ufunc, which will require casting:
getrid = np.frompyfunc(getridofnumbers, 1, 1)
x[getrid(x).astype(bool)]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `x = np.array([1,'hello',2,'world'])`, numpy converts everything to string type.

If it is one dimensional array, you can use:

`y = np.array([i for i in x if not i.replace(".","",1).replace("e+","").replace("e-","").replace("-","").isnumeric()])`

to get all non-numeric values.

It can identify all floats with negative sign and and e+/e- )

like, for input: `x = np.array([1,'hello',+2e-50,'world', 2e+50,-2, 3/4, 6.5 , "!"])`
output will be : `array(['hello', 'world', '!'], dtype='<U5')`